# Functional combinator for filter then map

Tags: scala, functional-programming, combinators

I have a collection of tuples of type `(Boolean, A)` which I'd like to transform to a collection of `A`.

Is there a well known combinator which does the following?

```
.filter(_._1).map(_._2)
```

Comment: What do you expect the `filter` to do?

Comment: One point of terminology: when you say you have a functor over `(Boolean, A)`, I'd expect a functor that allows you to map over the right side of the tuple, which apparently isn't what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, I admit my terminology is wrong when I created this question. I have made an edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.collect { case (b, x) if b => x }` (`filter` isn't an operation available on functors in general, so it depends on what exactly you mean by "I have a functor over the tuple (Boolean, A)")